# Dynamic v-model modifiers?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

Vue features [v-model modifiers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#modifiers) such as `number`:

```html
<input v-model.number="age" />
```

I am writing an abstract Field component which wraps the `input` and may need *optionally* include the modifier.

How can it be done (other than `v-if`/`v-else` the whole inputs)?

Comment: `v-model` is sugar syntax. Use the longer form with `:value` and `@input`.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states:

> The number modifier is applied automatically if the input has
> type="number".

So if you add a prop for the type in your component and than bind that to the input, setting type to number on your component will automatically set the `v-model.number`.

Comment: I don't wanna do that because browsers render `type="number"` differently from `type="text"` (spinners etc.). I want to use `type="text"` with `v-model.number`.

Comment: Okay, than you might want to create your own modifier on the v-model of your component? Then you can use v-model.number on your own component and convert the output on update. See https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#handling-v-model-modifiers